# Por que a $_SESSION não está acessível em outra página

Tags: php, session

No meu site tenho uma página de perfil, quando o usuário faz login ele é redirecionado para a página `perfil.php`, esse login é realizado na página `entrar.php`.

Então na página entrar eu tenho:

**entrar.php**

```
<?php include "controller/functions.php";?>
<?php include "controller/db_ss_user_entrar.php";?>
<?php include "view/doctype.php";?>
<html>
    <?php include "view/head.php";?>
    <body>
        <?php include "view/header.php";?>
        <div id="content">
            <?php include "view/wrap_entrar.php";?>
        </div>
            <?php include "view/footer.php";?>
        <script src=js/entrar.js></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

O arquivo relevante ao login é `db_ss_user_entrar.php`. A parte relativa a sessão está indicada no código abaixo:

**db_ss_user_entrar.php**

```
<?php
include 'db_conect.php';
$place_email = "Insira um email";
$place_senha = "Insira uma senha";*/
$email_place = "Insira um email";
$email_err = "";
$senha_place = "Insira uma senha";
$senha_err = "";
$error = 0;
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
{       $value_email =  mysqli_real_escape_string($con, preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['email']));
        if(empty($_POST["email"]) || 
                $value_email === "" || 
                $value_email === "Email inválido" || 
                !preg_match("/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i",$value_email))
        {       $value_email = "Email inválido";
                $error++;
        }else
        {       $value_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['email']));
        }
        $value_senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['senha']);
        if(empty($_POST["senha"]) || 
                !preg_match("/^\S*$/",$value_senha))
        {       $place_senha = "Senha inválida";
                $error++;
        }else
        {       $value_senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['senha']);
        }
        if($error !== 0)
        {       return false;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT input_nome,input_email,input_tel,input_senha,user_id,img_perfil FROM form_user WHERE input_email = '$value_email' AND input_senha = '$value_senha'";
        $result = $con->query($sql);
        $linha = $result->num_rows;
        if($linha != 1)
        {       $error++;
                $value_email = "Email inválido";
                $value_senha = "";
                $place_senha = "Senha inválida";
                $con->close();
                return false;
        }else //<-----------------Aqui começa o trecho relativo a sessão
        {       $row = $result->fetch_object();
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['ss_nome'] = $row->input_nome;
                $_SESSION['ss_email'] = $row->input_email;
                $_SESSION['ss_id_user'] = $row->user_id;
                $_SESSION['ss_tel'] = $row->input_tel;
                $_SESSION['ss_s_user'] = $row->input_senha;
                if(($row->img_perfil) === "")
                {   $_SESSION['ss_img_perfil'] = "img/icon_perfil_bluegrey.svg";
                }else
                {   $_SESSION['ss_img_perfil'] = $row->img_perfil;
                }
                header('location:perfil');
        }
}
?>
```

Até aqui corre tudo bem o usuário é redirecionado para a página de perfil e dando um `var_dump($_SESSION)`, eu vejo que a sessão tem os dados que preciso.

O problema ocorre na página perfil que possui um link que permite o usuário a editar o perfil:

```
<a href="editar-perfil" class="btn_fImob">Editar Perfil</a>
```

Então na página `editar-perfil.php` eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php include "controller/functions.php";?>
<?php include "controller/security.php";?>
<?php include "controller/db_select_user.php";?>
<?php include "view/doctype.php";?>
<html>
    <?php include "view/head.php";?>
    <body>
        <?php include "view/header.php";?>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="content_perfil">
                                <?php include 'view/wrap_perfil_edit.php';?>
            </div>
        </div>
            <?php include "view/footer.php";?>
    </body>
</html>
```

O problema é que ao ser redirecionado da página `perfil.php` para `editar-perfil.php`, a variável de sessão fica nula e automaticamente redireciona para entrar, o código que faz isso é do arquivo `security.php`:

**security.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['ss_email']))
{       session_destroy();
        unset ($_SESSION['ss_email']);
        header('location:entrar');
}
?>
```

Ou seja os dados da sessão não estão sendo passados para a página `editar-perfil.php`, e eu não entendo o porque.

Comment: Poderia verificar na página `editar-perfil.php` antes do include a session existe com var_dump

Comment: @dvd obrigado pela atenção, vem zaio.

Comment: Na verdade nem adiantaria, por o session_start(); está dentro da include ;/

Comment: Talvez fazendo o var_dump depois das includes

Comment: @dvd mesmo eu tirando os outros includes (comentando as linhas) e colocando no topo `session_start()` no arquivo `editar-perfil` a session fica vazia... é quebrar a cuca

Comment: Complicado... talvez um teste mais "cru"... faz um backup da página `editar-perfil.php` e esvazie ela toda e deixe apenas o session_start e o var_dump pra ver se está indo vazio... se tiver indo cheia, é algum código com problema

Comment: To com a cabeça cheia estava funcionando, não imagino o que pode ser vou dar uma esfriada

Comment: Tem algum framework a trabalhar por trás ou é tudo puro ?

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @Isac é puro...

Comment: Eu começava por fazer alguns testes de sanidade. Testando um `var_dump` da sessão no topo e ir navegando em várias páginas a ver se se mantem em algumas páginas/todas/nenhumas. Depois confirmava se os `warnings` estão ativos, pois se tiverem inativos pode não estar a ver um `headers already sent` que lhe vai fazer a sessão não funcionar. Isso seria o caso de estar a escrever qualquer caratere estranho antes de `session_start` ou diretamente ou por meio de inclusão de outro arquivo.

Answer (score -2):

Eu uso este código para a `$_SESSION`

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start();
}
$MM_authorizedUsers = "";
$MM_donotCheckaccess = "true";

function isAuthorized($strUsers, $strGroups, $UserName, $UserGroup) { 

  $isValid = False; 

  if (!empty($UserName)) { 
    $arrUsers = Explode(",", $strUsers); 
    $arrGroups = Explode(",", $strGroups); 
    if (in_array($UserName, $arrUsers)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (in_array($UserGroup, $arrGroups)) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
    if (($strUsers == "") && true) { 
      $isValid = true; 
    } 
  } 
  return $isValid; 
}

$MM_restrictGoTo = "../index.php";
if (!((isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) && (isAuthorized("",$MM_authorizedUsers, $_SESSION['MM_Username'], $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'])))) {   
  $MM_qsChar = "?";
  $MM_referrer = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  if (strpos($MM_restrictGoTo, "?")) $MM_qsChar = "&";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && strlen($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) > 0) 
  $MM_referrer .= "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $MM_restrictGoTo = $MM_restrictGoTo. $MM_qsChar . "accesscheck=" . urlencode($MM_referrer);
  header("Location: ". $MM_restrictGoTo); 
  exit;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Olá, não sei se sua session está inicializada no arquivo autoload, se não estiver, pode tentar. No meu caso estava e não funcionava. Retirei de lá efiz o seguinte:

```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

Já no controller onde precisava receber:

```
  session_start();
  print_r($_SESSION);
  die();
```

Espero que ajude!